# PostConstruct method not called in RequestScoped been

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jsf-2

I'm expecting the `@PostConstruct` method to get called every time I refresh the page in the `@RequestScoped` bean. But for some reason it doesn't. Neither does the default constructor.

I tried implementing a `filter` to disable the `cache`. I'm seeing the `doFilter` method getting called but it has no effect.

This is the code:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SearchResults implements Serializable {

    public SearchResults() {
        System.out.println("searchResults default constructor called");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("SearchResults.init CALLED");
    }
}
```

The filter's relevant method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("DisableCacheFilter.doFilter CALLED");

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

What am I missing?

ANSWER: I had changed the `annotation` in the `.java` from `SessionScoped` to `RequestScoped` but left the `ManagedBean` as session scoped in `faces-config`. Once I changed it it started working as expected:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>searchResults</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.app.pages.SearchResults</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: is `@RequestScoped` from the `javax.faces.bean` package?

Comment: No, it's from javax.annotation.PostConstruct. Should it be from the javax.faces.been?

Comment: i mean the @RequestScoped annotation not the PostConstruct

Comment: Yes, it's from javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped

Comment: can you show your xhtml where its called?

Comment: It's not called from the xhtml. I'm assuming it's part of the lifecycle of a ManagedBean.

Comment: No, you should access to it than the bean will be init on every request. If you dont use it, it won't be call @postconstruct

Comment: Access the PostConstruct from the xhtml? Are you sure? That kind of defies the purpose of having a bean lifecycle.

Comment: no, i mean if you use the managedbean in a xhtml on this time the bean will created and postconstruct will called in this "creation" process

Comment: But that's the issue, that it doesn't.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I just realized why you were asking this. Yes, I am accessing my searchResults bean through the xhtml.

Comment: Although the questions are not the same, I've closed this as dupe of your other question as the answer is basically exactly the same. Oh, please it's "bean", not "been".

Comment: Yes, you're right on both counts. Thanks.